# Execute PowerShell command in C# Cmdlet in the same PowerShell environment

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have written a PowerShell Cmdlet in C#. In this Cmdlet, I need the output of another PowerShell Command. However, this PowerShell Command is not accessible from a default PowerShell window and its module needs to be imported.

Suppose the name of this command is "New-Token" and it is accessible only on a special PowerShell window provided to me on a remote computer by my organization. My C# Cmdlet needs to call this command and get the output.

I used the following code snippet to run this command

```
            Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline();
            Command cmd = new Command("New-Token");
            pipeline.Commands.Add(cmd);
            Collection<PSObject> output = pipeline.Invoke();
            WriteObject(output);
```

When I run it on the PowerShell window where New-Token is imported, I get the error:

**The term 'New-Token' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.**

How can I make the C# cmdlet execute Powershell commands in the same PowerShell window in which it is called?